attempting to link libc statically with clang, ldd showing dynamic linking?
I'd like to compile a C program with system libraries (such as libc) linked statically, with all my other custom libraries (such as openssl) linked dynamically. When I compile a "Hello World" program in C with clang 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 20.04, I expect to see libc linked statically, however it's linked dynamically, and the linker adds on libgcc_s as well:
$ clang /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a main.c -o main
$ ldd main
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64-so.2

Trying a different suggestion yields the same result:
$ clang -Wl,-Bstatic -lc -Wl,-Bdynamic main.c -o main
$ ldd main
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64-so.2

Compiling without attempting to static linking libc yields the same result, just without libgcc_s.so.1 linked:
$ clang main.c -o main
$ ldd main
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64-so.2

Now, research says that glibc, which I'm using, shouldn't be statically linked--apparently musl is better for that. But is the above behavior expected, linking libc statically but showing a dynamic link, while also adding on libgcc_s? Is it in fact, possible to link glibc statically regardless of recommendation?

As you mentioned:

Now, research says that glibc, which I'm using, shouldn't be statically linked--apparently musl is better for that. But is the above behavior expected, linking libc statically but showing a dynamic link, while also adding on libgcc_s? Is it in fact, possible to link glibc statically regardless of recommendation?

Because glibc is heavily dependent on dynamic linking and other dynamic-linked components, it is designed for dynamic linking. When you statically link glibc, it does not mean that the entire libc is embedded within your binary. I would recommend you can study other methods, such as using another libc implementation like musl, bundling a shared library with your application or using Docker and other container technology to ensure a consistent runtime environment.
Hopefully this helps!

Nevermind statically linking libc is a bad idea in the first place - if the kernel interface changes your app is broken.  There's no ruling standard such as POSIX or the C standard itself defining a stable interface between libc and the kernel.

Per Red Hat:  "Static linking with the C/C++ runtime is not supported. This includes linking with any files that are part of the glibc-static or libstdc++-static packages. You may choose to link statically, but the resulting application binaries may fail to operate if any package in the installation is changed."

Thanks Alvin and Andrew, do you know why the linker brings in libgcc_s when linking libc statically? I see that when compiling with verbose output (both when attempting to link libc statically or dynamically) that ld has --as-needed -lgcc_s, so it must be needed when linking statically.
